# how to make animation inactive for some time period in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, delay, user-inactivity

here the jsfiddle link to my problem http://jsfiddle.net/XnnvD/35/ (not quite working)

I'll try explaining what the problem is, I have 3 sets of animation in jQuery

1- Image bounces and fades away after  some TimePeriod as below:

```
$('#homePageImage').animate(
                    { top: '50px' },
                    { queue: false, duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce' });
$('#homePageImage').delay(3000).effect('drop', { direction: "right" });
```

2- Set of images `.fadeIn()` randomly as below:

```
randNumArray = shuffle(randNumArray);
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{ $('#fs' + randNumArray[i]).delay(j += 200).fadeIn(j); }
```

3- Hovering over these images, will enlarge them as below:

```
$(function () {
            $("ul.thumb li").hover(function () {
                $(this).css({ 'z-index': '10' });
                $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: '-110px',
                    marginLeft: '-110px',
                    top: '50%',
                    left: '50%',
                    width: '174px',
                    height: '174px',
                    padding: '20px'
                }, 500);

            }, function () {
                $(this).css({ 'z-index': '0' });
                $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: '0',
                    marginLeft: '0',
                    top: '0',
                    left: '0',
                    width: '100px',
                    height: '100px',
                    padding: '5px'
                }, 500);
            });
        });
```

**The Problem:**
If the user hovers before the 1st set of animation is complete, the images don't `.fadeIn()` completely, and hence are partially/not visible

**What I want:**
I want the 3rd set (hovering to enlarge) to remain inactive till my 1st and 2nd set of animations are complete, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand - but it sounds like the ability to hover should not be triggered until the second animation finishes. Rather than delaying it, use an event to enable the hover code when the animation is over.

Comment: yes, the user shouldn't be able to hover until the 2nd animation finishes !

Comment: How about unbinding the animation for hover and re-binding when the animation finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Hover function in a SetTimeOut function like this

```
setTimeout((function () {
            $("ul.thumb li").hover(function () {
                $(this).css({ 'z-index': '10' });
                $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: '-110px',
                    marginLeft: '-110px',
                    top: '50%',
                    left: '50%',
                    width: '174px',
                    height: '174px',
                    padding: '20px'
                }, 500);

            }, function () {
                $(this).css({ 'z-index': '0' });
                $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: '0',
                    marginLeft: '0',
                    top: '0',
                    left: '0',
                    width: '100px',
                    height: '100px',
                    padding: '5px'
                }, 500);
            });
        }), *Put time in miliseconds*);
```

So this will ensure that the hover doesn't happen till the specified time period!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try calling the hover function as a callback function on the back of the second animation. In basic terms:

```
$("#homePageImage").fadeIn("slow", function() {

// enable hover function

});
```

Comment: the 2nd animation is in a loop !

Comment: Ok, how about an if statment in the loop which checks if it's the last iteration. If so, it will enable the function.

Comment: might as well do 8 iterations and call the 9th one separately !

Comment: You might aswell keep the loop intact to minimise code, but an if in the last phase of the loop ought to work no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to use a callback:

```
$('image').fadeIn('fast', function() {
  $('image').hover(function() {do stuff...});
});
```

Comment: the 2nd animation is in a loop !

Comment: Put it into a function and call the function.

Comment: `$('image').fadeIn('fast', function() {
hoveringActive();});
function hoveringActive() {$('image').hover(stuff);}`